# How do I use REST APIs with Azure Managed Identities?

Tags: python, azure, api, rest, virtual-machine

I was given a task in my internship which is to use REST APIs to check if a managed identity exists inside of a specific Azure service account, create it if it doesn't exist or delete it.
After this is done I have to do the same with storage accounts, basically we want to use Managed Identity for IaaS PostgreSQL and MSSQL backups on Azure VMs.

They linked 2 resources for reference:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-rest-vm#assign-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-to-an-existing-azure-vm

I've tried using the other api files that were already there as a reference but I'm not sure my changes are good since it's my first official time working with APIs, and using Azure. This is the format that I'm trying to follow

```
@app.route("/v1/initiate/<machine_id>", methods=["POST"])
@func_logger("cloudx_workflow_service", "state_machine_workflow")
def initiate_workflow(machine_id, **kwargs):
    """
    Initiate state machine workflow
    Args:
        machine_id:
        **kwargs:

    Returns:

    """
```

I'm open to any help, advice, resources you guys recommend.